# Массив с клиента на сервер с помощью GET или POST?

Tags: ajax, http, rest

Никаких мутаций данных не предполагается, массив необходим для получения некой информации из БД по `массиву c ID` (*например типа* `Long` *размером в 1-2к*).

С одной стороны, это по всем признакам GET, а с другой стороны слишком много возни и ограничений при разборе на серверной стороне, как по мне так POST куда лучше смотрится для таких задач и я использовал именно его всю свою жизнь. Но сегодня "босс" сказал - делай GET!

Нуждаюсь в твердом и уверенном мнении, приму в дар ссылки где концептуально и теоретически раскрыт данный вопрос.

[Например данная информация](https://github.com/dreikanter/paradigm.ru/blob/master/posts/2007-12-19_url-max-length.md) содержит, лично для меня, аргументы в пользу POST.

Comment: Добавьте код, которым пользуетесь, укажите также Вашу библиотеку или фреймвёрк, также пример данных которые отправляете

Comment: вопрос чисто теоретический, и я не думаю что есть смысл хоть в каких то листингах. пример данных в вопросе имеется.

Comment: Нужно отправить массив строк или более сложных структур?

Comment: @Nofate например Long, поправил вопрос. Но я не думаю что это принципиально в рамках моего вопроса, я хочу знать концептуально как правильно делать, если мы просто запрашиваем данные и не производим мутаций то это всегда GET, или всегда POST, или по ситуации?

Comment: @papiroca развернуто ответил вам ниже. По ситуации. Но обычно GET.

Comment: Концептуально - GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[статья которая расставила все точки над ё, в моем случае](http://handynotes.ru/2009/08/get-versus-pos.html)

самое полезное из нее, пожалуй
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*источник handynotes.ru*

Comment: Неплохой алгоритм. Но я бы еще добавил проверку "нужна ли защита от CSRF-атаки" (ведет на POST) и убрал проверку про выгоду пользователя (проще сделать GET чем думать).

Answer (score 1):

Нет никаких причин, по которым было бы нельзя отправить через GET массив. Способов передачи - масса, вопрос лишь в том что будет проще в рамках используемых лично вами библиотек.

```
/api/getbyids/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}...
/api/getbyids/{id1},{id2},{id3}...
/api/getbyids?ids={id1},{id2},{id3}...
/api/getbyids?id={id1}&id={id2}&id={id3}...
/api/getbyids?id1={id1}&id2={id2}&id3={id3}...
/api/getbyids?id[0]={id1}&id[1]={id2}&id[2]={id3}...
/api/getbyids?id[]={id1}&id[]={id2}&id[]={id3}...
```

Концептуальная разница между GET и POST заключается в том, что GET - это запрос ресурса, который может быть повторен, сохранен в кеше, запомнен в истории, передан другу, а POST - это вызов действия, которое делается однократно.

Comment: но есть ограничения на длину GET запроса, например. И нет причин по которым в js нельзя написать _var someval =_ , но ведь _someVal_ выглядит лучше.

Comment: @papiroca Тут все зависит от длины массива

Comment: ну допустим при длине массива в 1-2к id, вида 27354, например

Comment: @papiroca ну, большинство браузеров и такое смогут. Если прокси-сервера для динозавров посередине не окажется :) В стандарте жесткого ограничения на длину URI - нет.

Comment: https://github.com/dreikanter/paradigm.ru/blob/master/posts/2007-12-19_url-max-length.md вот например информация которая может заставить предпочитать POST

Comment: @papiroca ну вот, вы сами это раскопали :)

Comment: http://handynotes.ru/2009/08/get-versus-pos.html - пожалуй ответило на все мои вопросы, спасибо за помощь.